# Using two key-pairs in SSL Socket Connection

Tags: java, sockets, ssl-certificate, serversocket

I'd like to know how I can implement a server socket to let it able to identify and use 
correct certificate according with the certificate being used by client to proceed 
handshake communication with the server.

Explaining better,  in the server side is:

**AppServerSideSocket.jar**

- private keystore: **privateKeyApp** (type JKS,  generated with keytool)
- public keystore : **publicKeyApp**  (type JKS, shared with all clients)

And in the client side ...

**AppClientSideSocket.jar**
- public keystore : **publicKeyApp**

The **AppServerSideSocket.jar** listening clients requests and once received proocess 
information sent by clients

The **AppClientSideSocket.jar** connect with the server using SSL using **publicKeyApp** *without 
verify server hostname* and after handshake send information for the AppServerSideSocket application.

Now I've another client application, **AppClientSideSocketNEW.jar**, and this verify server hostname to make 
communication with the server. In this case, the CN used in the public certificate on the client side 
must be match with the hostname where **AppServerSideSocket.jar** are.

Originaly the connection was configured in this way on the server side:

```
if (usingSSLConn) {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "privateKeyApp");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "privateKeyAppPassword");

    SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    ServerSocket serverSocketApp = sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Port);

} else
    serverSocketApp = new ServerSocket(Port);
}
```

All the clients received the same publicKeyApp and connect with the server without verify hostname, so doesn't matter 
if the server where server socket application (**AppServerSideSocket.jar**) is installed  in the server with hostname is
badServer1.com  and the CN of key in privateKeyApp and publicKeyApp is setted with goodServer1.com, because all the clients don't verify hostname or the CN attribute of the key.

Bellow is showed a piece of this kind of connection:

```
private static final HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {

        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
 };
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", publicKey1);
 System.getProperties().setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", 
            "javax.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");     
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
 ...
 SOAPConnectionFactory soapConn = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
 SOAPConnection connection = soapConn.createConnection();
 ...     
 URL endpoint = new URL(hostname + ":" + port);
```

But the new client (**AppClientSideSocketNEW.jar**) do this verification obrigatorily, now is necessary provide a new certificate
for this client with new value for CN attribute reflecting the correct hostname CN where the server socket is.

I don't have access to second client and I'm sure that it do hostname verification.

So I created two new key-pair ceritificates (**privateKeyAppNew and publicKeyAppNew**) and aparently the communications happened 
with success between the server using this new key-pair and new client using this new public publicKeyAppNew key.

But I need continue to use the old key-pair for old clients. I'd like to know how can I deal with this.

Using a keymanager let me able to verify the client certificate on the server app when client try to connect and 
choose the apropriate and do the handshake using the correct certificate?

Or I need disctinct ssl socket connection in different ports for which kind of clients?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using two private keys (keystore) and two public keys (truststore) in one SSL Socket Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215667/using-two-private-keys-keystore-and-two-public-keys-truststore-in-one-ssl-so)

Comment: ... itself a duplicate of [Using more than one key-pair in SSL Socket Factory Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179717/using-more-than-one-key-pair-in-ssl-socket-factory-connection). All 3 asked by the same person...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a [Hostname Verifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html) in the connection you want to verify the CN of the server certificate.

Plenty of examples if you google e.g.

[Hostname verifier 1](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/) this creates a trust all names but you can modify it as you need
[HttpClient and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/httpclient-and-ssl) same in the answer her

Comment: Doesn't address the issue of how to use two keystores & truststores in the slightest.

Comment: @EJP:He has the keystores and obviously OP knows hot to use them.I answered exactly how the hostname validation can be done which is what the OP asks for

Comment: He asked 'how to implement a server socket ...'. HostnameVerifiers are for clients. Your answer remains irrelevant.