# When using a custom X509KeyManager Java is not able to determine a matching cipher suite for the SSL handshake

Tags: java, ssl, soap, jax-ws

I'm working with Java7 and JAX-WS 2.2.

For a SOAP web service I need to create a custom `X509KeyManager` in order to find the correct certificate for each connecting client in a JKS keystore.

However, I'm already struggling to get the my custom key manager running. So far I'm using the default one (retrieved from the initialized `KeyManagerFactory`) and it basically works - but of course it doesn't select the correct certificate. So the first idea was to create a custom `X509KeyManager` which holds the original key manager, only writes out some log messages but generally uses the default behaviour.

For some reason that doesn't work at all. The SSL handshake cannot be established. After the *ClientHello* the log shows the following error:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Thread-3, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1476877930 bytes = { 207, 226, 8, 128, 40, 207, 47, 180, 146, 211, 157, 64, 239, 13, 201, 92, 158, 111, 108, 44, 223, 136, 193, 251, 33, 202, 7, 90 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-3, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
Thread-3, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-3, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
Thread-3, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Thread-3, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Thread-3, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

I didn't remove any cipher suites at all to my knowledge! And the SSL handshake *can* be made with the same certificates.

This is my key manager:

```
public class CustomX509KeyManager extends X509ExtendedKeyManager
{
   private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( CustomX509KeyManager.class );
   private final X509KeyManager originalKeyManager;

   public CustomX509KeyManager(final X509KeyManager keyManager)
   {
      super();
      this.originalKeyManager = keyManager;
   }

   @Override
   public String chooseServerAlias(final String keyType, final Principal[] issuers,
     final Socket socket)
   {
      final String serverAliases=
            this.originalKeyManager.chooseServerAlias( keyType, issuers, socket );
      CustomX509KeyManager.LOG.info( "chooseServerAlias() " + serverAliases );
      return serverAliases;
   }

   ...
}
```

The other methods (not shown here) are just calling the corresponding methods in the `originalKeyManager` as well. During testing I never see the log message from the `chooseServerAlias()` method.

And it's initialized from another class in the `getSslContext()`method:

```
private KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory)
{
   final KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

   // replace any X509KeyManager with our own implementation
   for ( int i = 0; i < keyManagers.length; i++ )
   {
      if ( keyManagers[i] instanceof X509KeyManager )
      {
         keyManagers[i] =
               new CustomX509KeyManager( ( X509KeyManager ) keyManagers[i] );
      }
   }

   return keyManagers;
}

public SSLContext getSslContext()
{
  // create the KeyStore and load the JKS file
  final KeyStore keyStore = createKeyStore();

  // initialize key and trust manager factory
  final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory =
        KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
  keyManagerFactory.init( keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray() );
  final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
        TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
  trustManagerFactory.init( keyStore );

  // initialize the SSL context
  final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
  // sslContext.init( keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
  //      trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom() );
  sslContext.init( getKeyManagers( keyManagerFactory ),
        trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom() );
  return sslContext;
}
```

The commented lines show the original usage of the default key manager.

Any idea what's wrong? Why is the behaviour of using my `CustomX509KeyManager` so different than the default key manager that the handshake cannot be done? With the default key manager the encryption is negotiated for the TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA algorithm which is available with the custom key manager as well but for some reason not chosen.

#### Update 1

I'm trying to connect with openssl in client mode to the server now but the server encounters the same problem using SSL. When I use the TLS protocol then the additional error message

> Unsupported extension type_35, data:

appears.

#### Update 2

I can confirm that the above notice about unsupported extensions also appears upon successful handshakes so this is a false trace.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running this server-side or client-side?

Comment: Server side! I'm testing it with my reference client implemenation as well as with openssl _in client_.

Comment: `chooseClientAlias` is only used by the client, not by the server. I'm also not clear why you'd want to change the server certificate to match the client's IP address (if I understand what you're asking).

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I've edited the code example but the result is the same. I'm getting the impression that my key manager is never used. I've also removed the question about the matching of client IP address to stored certificates because the above error bugs me for some days now and I really want to get it working.

Comment: I don't see how you can even compile that code; param1 of `X509KeyManager.chooseServerAlias` is type `String` not `String[]`, thus my compiler complains the `@Override` method isn't an override and the call to the original method has incompatible types. If I fix that, and change the `LOG` to `System.out` and add scaffolding to call it, it works for me.

Comment: (ninjad) PS: extension 35 is SessionTicket rfc4507 which is implemented by OpenSSL but not Java/JSSE. A TLS server can simply ignore extensions it doesn't support; by omitting them from ServerHello, the client doesn't use or expect the extension behavior.

Comment: Sorry, code example fixed. Very interesting that the code works for you! Thanks for verifying it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a few days of trial & error I finally found my mistake!

In Java 7 a custom key manager should extend the [X509ExtendedKeyManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedKeyManager.html) which forces you to implement five methods of the interface `X509KeyManager`. However, there are two additional methods in the class `X509ExtendedKeyManager` which are not declared as abstract but **must** be overwritten for proper usage:

- `chooseEngineClientAlias(String[], Principal[], SSLEngine)`
- `chooseEngineServerAlias(String, Principal[], SSLEngine)`

After overwriting and implementing the methods by delegating the call to my `originalKeyManager` (which became of type `X509ExtendedKeyManager` as well) the SSL handshake finally succeeded.

Comment: Wow! How on earth did you figure that one out! Amazing! :) Thanks!

Comment: @Markus L. Please post X509ExtendedKeyManager  wrapper class code you have.

I extended X509ExtendedKeyManager  & implemented X509KeyManager  as well, still I could not see log message in override methods and SSL Handshake is failing as well.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't read keyfile anywhere in the code snippet. This is the reason of SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL. I suggest you implement `X509KeyManager` and read the file in constructor, so it can be used letter to select appropriate key. Something down this line (not all required methods depicted for the sake of short answer):

```
public class CustomX509KeyManager implements X509KeyManager
{
   private final KeyStore keyStore;
   private final String alias;
   private final char[] password;

   public CustomX509KeyManager(final String keyStoreFile, final char[] password, final String alias)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
   {
       this.alias = alias;
       this.password = password;
       synchronized(keyStoreFile)
       {
          InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
          keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
          keyStore.load(stream, password);
          stream.close();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias)
   {
       try {
           return (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password);
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias)
    {
        try {
            java.security.cert.Certificate[] certs = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
            if (certs == null || certs.length == 0)
                return null;
            X509Certificate[] x509 = new X509Certificate[certs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++)
                x509[i] = (X509Certificate)certs[i];
            return x509;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }          
    }

}
```

and then use it like

```
sslContext.init(new X509KeyManager[] { 
                    new CustomX509KeyManager(keyStoreFile, 
                        keyStorePass.toCharArray(), alias) }, null, null);
```

Comment: The JKS key store is read in the method `createKeyStore()`. I see the SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL also upon a successful SSL handshake. I'm using a two-way authentication that's why I'm using a trust store as well for the SSL context.

Comment: Interesting observation: If I declare the class like you do (without extending from `X509ExtendedKeyManager` but implementing the `X509KeyManager` interface) I get the notice `X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use`.