In a Java HttpsServer, how does Java know what cert to pass back to client?
I have a keystore with a self-signed certificate, created like this:
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias self_signed -keypass mypass -keystore mystore.jks -storepass mypass

And I have a HttpsServer server initialized like this:
    // Initialise the HTTPS server
    HttpsServer httpsServer = HttpsServer.create(address, 0);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    // Initialise the keystore
    String pw = "mypass";
    char[] keyStorePassword = pw.toCharArray();
    char[] keyPassword = pw.toCharArray();
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    File keyStoreFile = new File(Context.APP_STATE.getKeyStoreFile());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);
    ks.load(fis, keyStorePassword);

    // Set up the key manager factory
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, keyPassword);

    // Set up the trust manager factory
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(ks);

    // Set up the HTTPS context and parameters
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    ...<setting HttpsConfigurator omitted for brevity...

The above code works, but when a browser connects to my server, how does the server know to return the self-signed certificate without an alias having been specified?  Is it because when there's only one entry in the keystore it always uses that?  What if I had multiple entries in my keystore - how, could the above code be modified to specify a specific entry?

I'm pretty sure every certificate in the keystore gets used.

@VGR my question is more about the how?  If a client (browser) tries to establish a connection, how does the server know which certificate to present to the browser, if there's more than one in the keystore?  Does the server send back all of them and let the client choose?

Using the default X509[Extended]KeyManager if there is more than one suitable privatekey entry with cert or chain in the keystore, it picks the first one it finds in an arbitrary enumeration. To do otherwise, write your own implementation; it is sufficient to wrap the standard one and override only choose[Engine]ServerAlias (or Client in the opposite case). Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179717/using-more-than-one-key-pair-in-ssl-socket-factory- and nearly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423013/java---how-can-i-select- a-certificate-

@VGR+ an SSL/TLS server (also a client) can only use one EE cert (plus any chain CA certs for it) in a connection and must also use (thus must have) the matching privatekey; for Java by default these must be in a privatekey entry in the keystore used. A server can have available multiple sets of key+cert(s) and choose one in several ways; Java server by default only limits to the negotiated ciphersuite if <= TLS1.2 and the client-specified signature algorithms if 1.2 or 1.3.

BTW wolfman: in Java 9 up keytool by default creates a PKCS12 keystore not a JKS; however in 8u60 up the JKS implementation has a feature(?) to read PKCS12 as well. And in 9 up you can call KeyStore.getInstance(File ksfile, {char[] pw | LoadStoreParameter}) to have it determine the type and load it for you.

@dave_thompson_085 thanks a whole bunch for this info - I think it actually answers my questions!  Much appreciated.
